# Adding custom user registration page in Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I am using `Identity Server 4` as `Token Service` for my `.Net Core` application. I can't find a way to add a custom `user registration` page.  I could add `login`, `logout` pages as shown below.

```
   services.AddIdentityServer(
                options =>
                    {
                        options.UserInteractionOptions.LoginUrl = "/ui/login";
                        options.UserInteractionOptions.LogoutUrl = "/ui/logout";
                    });
```

I remember there is a way to add custom `register` and `forgot password` pages in `Identity Server 3` as shown below.

```
   AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        IdentityProviders = ConfigureAdditionalIdentityProviders,
                        LoginPageLinks = new LoginPageLink[] { 
                            new LoginPageLink{
                                Text = "Register",
                                Href = "localregistration"
                            },
                             new LoginPageLink{
                                Text = "Forgot Password?",
                                Href = "~/forgotpassword",
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I cannot find similar feature in `Identity Server 4` . Can any one help me out figuring this out. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

User management is not a feature of [Identity Server 4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/dev/) . You should implement own user management system. Or use aspnet identity to manage users, [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/dev/SpaWithAspId3AndIdSvr4/src/SpaWithAspId3AndIdSvr4/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L99) is an example of aspnet identity with Identity Server4.

Comment: Thanks Adem, I already implemented Identity for user management. But i want the feature to redirect the user to registration form when he clicks on register.  It was there in `IdentityServer3` but not in the latest one.

Comment: Did you see this example https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/SpaWithAspId3AndIdSvr4?

Comment: Yes, but that is more of MVC handled. I need to be able to configure the Views in  `Identity Server 4`. They have give customization for `login, logout `but not for register. I am just wondering there is a workaround.

Comment: Links broken and thats why LINK ONLY ANSWERS are disliked.